# Take backup of SQL database from remote server to local computer across domains

Tags: backup, permissions, database, sql

So in this scenario there are two computers:

1. A remote server hosting SQL that is not connected to a domain.
2. A local computer that is connected to a domain.

SQL Server Management Studio is installed on the local computer and I need to be able to take a backup of the database and have the .bak file written to a folder on the local computer instead of on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Steps to provide access to a shared folder

1. Create a shared folder on the computer where the backup will be written, and share with "Everyone." "Everyone" should have full control. Note that if both machines are on the same domain it is possible that this is the only necessary step.
   [image: Folder Properties]
2. Edit Local Security Policy: set "Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options > Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users" to Enabled.
   [image: Local Security Policy]
3. Edit Local Security Policy: add the name of the shared folder to "Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options > Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users." Note that this value is looking for the name of the folder, not the path.
   [image: Local Security Policy]
4. **Restart the computer or else the Local Security Policies will not have taken effect.**

### Now you can point the backup path to your shared folder

As usual, right click on database and go to "Tasks > Back Up..."
[image: SSMS Backup]

Add the full path to the shared folder and the name of your .bak file and all should go as planned. 
[image: Backup Path]